# In PostgreSQL what does hashed subplan mean?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, sql-execution-plan

I want to know how the optimizer rewrote the query and how to read the execution plan in PostgreSQL
Here is the sample code.

```
DROP TABLE ords;
CREATE TABLE ords (
ORD_ID INT NOT NULL,
ORD_PROD_ID VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
ETC_CONTENT VARCHAR(100));
ALTER TABLE ords ADD CONSTRAINT ords_PK PRIMARY KEY(ORD_ID);
CREATE INDEX ords_X01 ON ords(ORD_PROD_ID);
INSERT INTO ords
SELECT i
      ,chr(64+case when i <= 10 then i else 26 end)
      ,rpad('x',100,'x')
  FROM generate_series(1,10000) a(i);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ords WHERE ORD_PROD_ID IN ('A','B','C');

DROP TABLE delivery;
CREATE TABLE delivery (
ORD_ID INT NOT NULL,
VEHICLE_ID VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
ETC_REMARKS VARCHAR(100));
ALTER TABLE delivery ADD CONSTRAINT delivery_PK primary key (ORD_ID, VEHICLE_ID);
CREATE INDEX delivery_X01 ON delivery(VEHICLE_ID);
INSERT INTO delivery
SELECT i
     , chr(88 + case when i <= 10 then mod(i,2) else 2 end)
     , rpad('x',100,'x')
  FROM generate_series(1,10000) a(i);

analyze ords;
analyze delivery;
```

This is the SQL I am interested in.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ords a
 WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM delivery b
                  WHERE a.ORD_ID = b.ORD_ID
                    AND b.VEHICLE_ID IN ('X','Y')
                 )
         OR a.ORD_PROD_ID IN ('A','B','C')
         );
Here is the execution plan
| Seq Scan on portal.ords a (actual time=0.038..2.027 rows=10 loops=1)                                           |
|   Output: a.ord_id, a.ord_prod_id, a.etc_content                                                               |
|   Filter: ((alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2) OR ((a.ord_prod_id)::text = ANY ('{A,B,C}'::text[]))) |
|   Rows Removed by Filter: 9990                                                                                 |
|   Buffers: shared hit=181                                                                                      |
|   SubPlan 1                                                                                                    |
|     ->  Index Only Scan using delivery_pk on portal.delivery b (never executed)                                |
|           Index Cond: (b.ord_id = a.ord_id)                                                                    |
|           Filter: ((b.vehicle_id)::text = ANY ('{X,Y}'::text[]))                                               |
|           Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                      |
|   SubPlan 2                                                                                                    |
|     ->  Index Scan using delivery_x01 on portal.delivery b_1 (actual time=0.023..0.025 rows=10 loops=1)        |
|           Output: b_1.ord_id                                                                                   |
|           Index Cond: ((b_1.vehicle_id)::text = ANY ('{X,Y}'::text[]))                                         |
|           Buffers: shared hit=8                                                                                |
| Planning:                                                                                                      |
|   Buffers: shared hit=78                                                                                       |
| Planning Time: 0.302 ms                                                                                        |
| Execution Time: 2.121 ms
```

I don't know how the optimizer transformed the SQL.

- What is the final SQL the optimizer rewrote?
- I have only one `EXISTS` sub-query in the SQL above, why are there two sub-plans?
- What does "hashed Sub-Plan 2" mean?

I would appreciate it if anyone share a little knowledge with me.

Comment: The optimiser doesn't output SQL code.

Comment: I think the optimzer transforms the SQL we provide and calculate the cost of the rewritten query. I want to know what the final transformed SQL would be.

Comment: It transforms it into a query plan, not into SQL code.

Comment: Bergi, you are right. I could not distinguish  the optimizer from the query rewriter.

Answer (score 4):

You have the misconception that the optimizer rewrites the SQL statement. That is not the case. Rewriting the query is the job of the *query rewriter*, which for example replaces views with their definition. The optimizer comes up with a sequence of execution steps to compute the result. It produces a *plan*, not an SQL statement.

The optimizer plans two alternatives: either execute subplan 1 for each row found, or execute subplan 2 once (note that it is independent of `a`), build a hash table from the result and probe that hash for each row found in `a`.

At execution time, PostgreSQL decides to use the latter strategy, that is why subplan 1 is never executed.

Comment: Do you know the basis for that decision is?  I thought it would be whether the hash table was starting to overrun work_mem, but experimental that does not seem to be it.

Comment: jjanes, SubPlan 1 has nothing to do with hash tables and SubPlan 1 was never executed. The optimizer executed SubPlan 2 and the optimizer used a hash table which didn't overrun work_mem. I guess if the optimizer predicted it would overrun work_mem, then it didn't execute SubPlan 2. It would have executed SubPlan1, if it had predicted it would overrun  a hash table in SubPlan2.

Comment: @jjanes No, I don't understand how the decision was made. I tried to explain the execution plan.

Comment: Laurenz, here is my estimation of how the decision was made. In the problematic SQL, we can only see the estimated cost of the query plan where the exist Subquery didn't collapse. When you add OFFSET 0 in the exist Subquery, the estimated cost is identical to the problematic SQL. I guess behind the scene the optimizer also calculated the cost of the execution plan where the exist Subquery collapsed which uses SubPlan2  When the Subquery collapse happens, the estimated cost is a lot lower. So the optimizer chose SubPlan2 not executing SubPlan1.

Comment: Why does it matter so much which subplan is chosen? The query is very cheap, and I think it doesn't matter either way.

Comment: Well, the real SQL in my production system had a lot of data, which had long elapsed time. Below is the explanation how I made the query run faster. https://www.postgresdba.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=C05&wr_id=119&page=0&sca=&sfl=&stx=&spt=0&page=0&cwin=#c_121

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  I tracked down the basis for the decision.  The deferral to run time was never meaningfully implemented, and was recently removed (41efb8340877e8ffd0023bb).  The decision is made based on info available to the planner, and is now made by the planner.

Comment: @jjanes Interesting! Thanks for the research.